# how to launch or invoke microsoft tag reading app from within my android application?

Tags: android, microsoft-tag

Hi I would like to know how to invoke Microsoft tag reader app from within my android application, like as soon as my application opens the tag reader should be invoked automatically. Any code snippet regarding this query is viable, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity onCreate, add the following lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); 
intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.tag.app.reader");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

The easiest way to figure out the correct package name for any application is by looking at `LogCat` while launching the activity (filter on `ActivityManager`).